# Pandas data frame indexing error while index exists

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm trying to add values to a pandas data frame based on the combinations of a user's and an agent's choices. Here's what i tried so far.

```
import random 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product 

ls = np.zeros((9,3))
choices = ['R','P','S']

df = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns = list(choices), index=[''.join(l) for l in 
product(choices, repeat=2)])
user_choices = ['R','S']
agent_choices = ['P','R']
i = 0 

while i < 1000:
i +=1 
user_choice = random.choice(choices)
agent_choice = random.choice(choices)
user_choices.append(user_choice)
agent_choices.append(agent_choice)
df[user_choices[i-1]][np.char.add(user_choices[i-2] ,agent_choices[i-2])] +=1
```

This results to getting an indexing error while the indexes exist.

Expected output should be as this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYEdN.png) but obviously populated

Comment: please add some examples of your data set as well as expected output. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your error, replace `np.char.add` with a simple string addition like `stringA + stringB`.

[np.char.add](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.add.html#numpy-char-add) returns a ndarray, which you can't index on. You want a simple string

Comment: Hi Lukas i've tried that already before adding the np.char.add and it didn't work

Comment: replacing it with `df[user_choices[i-1]][user_choices[i-2] + agent_choices[i-2]] +=1` works for me